# Redirect to a different url on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have Create Products page with a url like *"/product/create"*.

It has multiple tabs about various categories of that product. When the tab-1 data is submitted (with AJAX) a product is created on the server side (stored in DB) but the url is still "/product/create".

I want to redirect this user to *"/product/{product_id}"* if this user tries to reload page after the product is created (i.e after the first AJAX call on tab-1). There can be multiple AJAX requests for the remaining tabs.

I tried the flashing data using but it's lost in subsequent AJAX requests.

```
session()->flash('foo','bar');
```

Is there any way to keep data until the next reload and redirect to edit route if that product is created? Or any other possible solutions to my problem.

Comment: So change the url when the call is successful with the history api....

Comment: All tabs are for creating product? What will happen is someone submit data from multiple tab?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be the most elegant solution, but for Chrome you can use the localStorage function. For example:

```
if (typeof localStorage.getItem('visited') != 'string') {
  localStorage.setItem('visited', 'anything here');
} else {
  localStorage.removeItem('visited');
  window.location.href = 'https://www.example.com';
}
```

Comment: I can try **localStorage** but it'll be a headache to erase those items when the user goes to some other page. Similar to my comment on Dalton's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just redirect the user when he creates the product?

In JavaScript, supposing that the product ID is in a variable called `product_id` it would be something like:

```
window.location.href = "/product/"+product_id;
```

If you don't want the page to be reloaded, use a PushState

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" }; //Something to the browser to know the state if user go back and forward again
history.pushState(stateObj, "NewTitle", "NewURL");
```

PushState navigation is something complex that should be added to the full webpage to give it a better look. [MDN Documentation for PushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Answer (score 0):

I think since you are using AJAX for your submissions, the best way would be that you ensure that your {product_id} is returned with the AJAX response, so you can build your refresh links. In Javascript (jQuery) pseudocode this would be something like:

```
// AJAX function call to createProduct
function createProduct() {
  $.post('ajax-url-end-point',{payload-data}, function (ajax_response){
    if(response){
       //build your refresh url with response
       var refreshUrl = "http://<domain>/product/"+response.productid;
       localStorage.setItem('refreshUrl', refreshUrl);
       window.location.href = refreshUrl
    }
  },'text');
}

// On reload check for the refreshUrl
$.document.ready(function() {
   if(localStorage.getItem("refreshUrl")){
      window.location.href = localStorage.getItem("refreshUrl");
   }
});
```

On your /product/{product_id} page, you can run a JS to erase the refreshUrl local storage item based on your own specific criteria.

Comment: The problem with your solution is if the user creates a product ("refreshUrl" is set), goes to some other page on the website and then tries to create a new product he/she will redirected to "refreshUrl" (because it's still there and not erased) to the previous product.